# Problem with handmade counter script using PHP and mySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have  "handmade" mini counter script, that count users and write data to mysql db. If user comes once, the script do unique query, if comes more than once do non-unique query. If user agent is bot and comes once, the script do unique query for bot and if comes more than once do non-unique query for bot. Also my script do some smart things, like: if admin tagged ip in db like non-bot, next time script put data like it's not bot ip, and reverse if admin tagged ip in db like bot, next time script put data like it's a bot ip.

But i have a problem with this smart things. If i tagged comes ip non-bot, next time script ignore this rule and write in db like comes ip is bot, and reverse to.

Please help me to solve this problem

```
<?php

    // name of bot ip query in DB
    $DO_BOT = "irobot";
    // name not bot ip query
    $DO_NOT_BOT = "imreal";

    //-- Create connection
    $conishua = new mysqli($sv_name, $ur_name, $multipass, $db_name);
    $conishua->set_charset('utf8');

    //-- Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

        // Just for report error uncheck under this line
        /* echo "Failed to connect to DB: " . mysqli_connect_error(); */
        die (mysqli_error($conishua));
        return false;

    }

    else {

#IF DB EXIST DO A QUERY
            $stmt = $conishua->prepare("SELECT (id) FROM `$tabname` WHERE ip = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $ip_clear);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rs = $stmt->get_result();
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);

            //-- If user ip not exist and not bot do uniq query
            if ($rs && $data[0] < 1 && !empty($hash_clear) && isset($hash_clear) && !$BADBOT && !$MY_IP && $BOT_AGENT === FALSE && substr_count($ip_clear, ".") == 3) {

                $stmt = $conishua->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tabname` (ip, agent, date, time, resolution, uniq, hash, device, imreal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $ip_clear, $agent_clear, $ddate_clear, $ttime_clear, $resolution_clear, $uniq_clear, $hash_clear, $device_clear, $DO_NOT_BOT);
                $stmt->execute();

            }

            //-- If user ip exist and ip's is not bot do non-uniq query and doubble
            else if ($rs && $data[0] >= 1 && !empty($hash_clear) && isset($hash_clear) && $data['date'] != $ddate && $data['time'] != $ttime && $data['hash'] != $hash  && !$BADBOT && !$MY_IP && $BOT_AGENT === FALSE && substr_count($ip_clear, ".") == 3) {

                $stmt = $conishua->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tabname` (ip, agent, date, time, resolution, hash, device, imreal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $ip_clear, $agent_clear, $ddate_clear, $ttime_clear, $resolution_clear, $hash_clear, $device_clear, $DO_NOT_BOT);
                $stmt->execute();

            }

            //-- If user ip not exist and ip's is bot do uniq query
            else if ($rs && $data[0] < 1 && !empty($hash_clear) && isset($hash_clear) && !$BADBOT && !$MY_IP && $BOT_AGENT === TRUE && substr_count($ip_clear, ".") == 3) {

                $stmt = $conishua->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tabname` (ip, agent, date, time, resolution, uniq, is_bot, hash, device) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $ip_clear, $agent_clear, $ddate_clear, $ttime_clear, $resolution_clear, $uniq_clear, $DO_BOT, $hash_clear, $device_clear);
                $stmt->execute();

            }

            //-- If user ip exist and ip's is bot do non-uniq query
            else if ($rs && $data[0] >= 1 && !empty($hash_clear) && isset($hash_clear) && $data['date'] != $ddate && $data['time'] != $ttime && $data['hash'] != $hash && !$BADBOT && !$MY_IP && $BOT_AGENT === TRUE && substr_count($ip_clear, ".") == 3) {

                $stmt = $conishua->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tabname` (ip, agent, date, time, resolution, is_bot, hash, device) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $ip_clear, $agent_clear, $ddate_clear, $ttime_clear, $resolution_clear, $DO_BOT, $hash_clear, $device_clear);
                $stmt->execute();

            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unrelated: you could put all those `$IPBot_Qxx`s into a loop

Comment: @user24343... maybe, but how...? Please do an example.. And my problem not in this.. thank you for answer.

Comment: use a `foreach` to iterate over the strings, then do `$BOT_AGENT = $BOT_AGENT || stripos($useragent, $string_from_loop)` inside. I know it doesn't solve the problem, but it would make the code more readable so that a potential helper isn't scared away by the big block.

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion.

Comment: @user24343 ok..... thank you

Comment: @Dharman... why you clicking minus on my question? If you trying to read, you'll see that my question is not about security! And your answer not solve my problem!

Comment: @Dharman i do an update specially for you. Hope you are satisfied. Even with such changes, my problem has not been solved. The script still works fine, but without the required changes!

Comment: @Dharman so why you clicking minus on my question?

Comment: @АнжеликаДемьяненко Why are you checking if `$data[0]` is `<` or `>=` 1? This should be checking that the result of `mysqli_num_rows` is greater than 0 and therefore whether rows returned, i.e. record exists.

Comment: @АнжеликаДемьяненко Also, you're using both indices and keys to attempt accessing column data on `$data`. As you've used `mysql_fetch_array`, you can only access the `$data` array on indices, i.e. `$data[0]`. If you want to use keys, i.e. `$data['time']` you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` otherwise that key will be `null`. Another point, you also have only selected `id` column in your `$stmt` query, therefore `$data['date']`, `$data['time']` and `$data['hash']` will all be null. This is likely where your conditions fail.

Comment: @LeonStorey... Sorry, but nothing change.. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @АнжеликаДемьяненко Could you update the code above with the latest edit please?